# Tweet button issue on website

Tags: jquery, html, button, twitter

[expected output is like this tweet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BFyN.png)

I am trying to add a tweet button to a webpage where when user clicks the contents of that page will be posted to twitter. I want something like given in the linked picture. it displays the title of the blog post, first image in the post alongwith some text from the post followed by website URL. and when click on it, it will open the exact post page.

I am embedding default twitter share button with page title and URL. but it is not embedding the page content and picture.

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class=" twitter-share-button" data-via="someusername" data-related="someusername" data-show-count="false" target="_blank"></a><script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

this button picks the page title and page url. how to add one picture and few of the contents in this tweet also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use meta tags for social media content.

For Twitter, look into [Twitter Cards](https://dev.twitter.com/cards/overview)

Comment: thank you for the response, but twitter cards are completely different thing, that shows the summary about the web site or page or somethign like that. I just need when user click on particular article its title, url, first image and few lines of first paragraph to be tweeted, i got the title and url, but dont understand how to get first image and fest text lines to be a part of the tweet.

Comment: Do you have an example? I don't understand why you can't add meta tags to the article's page.

Comment: sorry I do not have any example, can you please elaborate how to add article content to meta and then to tweet.  sorry i am not an experienced one at social media buttons. was trying twitter help since Saturday but did not find any thing suitable to do as per my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

As Bobby Spiers mentioned in his response solution to mu question is twitter cards. I did it through summar cards. And it worked. Twitter cards documentation available on twitter help can guide to get it  done correctly.